# How to Run PowerCalc (Power Calculator) on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, calculator

A while ago Microsoft released an upgrade to their Calc application for Win XP called [PowerCalc](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/xp-downloads#2TC=powertoys).  It was a great little calculator application with few bells and whistles but easy to use.  Unfortunately, it was tied to Windows XP and would not work on any other windows machine.  Several [enterprising](http://dan.hersam.com/2010/11/10/powercalc-in-windows-7/) [individuals](http://blog.red-stars.net/technology/software/hacking-windows-xp-powertoy-calculator-to-run-in-vista/) hacked the executable to get the program working on Windows 7 and Vista. However I recently upgraded to Windows 8.

Has anyone figured out how to get PowerCalc to work on Windows 8?

Comment: have you tried running the version from your 2nd link (the one on http://blog.red-stars.net/) - I don't see why that approach wouldn't work on Win8 if it's just a version checking issue as opposed to not being compatible.

Comment: I have tried running the executable, it does not work.  I have not tried opening a hex editor and messing with it.

Comment: Hmmm... this is odd, it started working all of a sudden. I don't really know what I did differently.

Comment: Anyone knows where the find the application again? I can't find it in Microsoft downloads anymore.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure there's an easier way, but this is what worked for me...

1. Download the [Windows 8 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_EAC=300135395)
2. Install the SDK, then install Orca from

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\Orca-x86_en-us.msi`
3. Run the PowerCalc installer -- it will fail, but will extract the msi installer to

   `C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\Calculator Powertoy for Windows XP.msi`
4. Copy the msi to your Desktop
5. Right click the copied msi and select "Edit with Orca"
6. In Orca under the "LaunchCondition" table, delete the "VersionNT = 501" condition, then save and exit Orca
7. Install PowerCalc from the modified msi
8. Open PowerCalc.exe with a HEX editor such as [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/download.php)

   `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PowerCalc.exe`
9. In PSPad, select Search > Go to line `$13E1`, then replace `0F 84 B9 00 00 00` with `90 90 90 90 90 90`
10. Launch the powertoy calculator and enjoy!

Comment: Works like a charm and thanks. BTW, I tried on Windows 7 and Orca was not required but the installer runs directly with Windows XP compatibility mode enabled

Comment: I successfully did this on Windows 10. Skip the first couple of steps. Run the PowerCalc installer with Windows XP compatibility mode to install (step 7), then follow step 8 onward.